# SearchView sem retorno algum no Android

Tags: android, actionbar

Implementei uma SearchView e coloquei um Toast para ver se estava funcionando assim que eu digitasse algo na busca. Porém o Toast não é exibido, não aparece nenhum erro no Logcat. A busca está em uma ActionBar. Quando clico no ícone de busca, ela expande para poder digitar porém assim que e aperto "enter" / "confirmar" o Toast não aparece.

Essa é a parte onde eu estou chamando a Search

```
public void pesquisar(MenuItem item){

        searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                            return false;
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sair:
                this.finish();

            case R.id.sobre:
                return true;

            case R.id.cadastrar:
                Intent telaCadastro = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CadastroMaterias.class);
                startActivity(telaCadastro);

            case R.id.pesquisar:
                pesquisar(item);

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item android:id="@+id/sobre"
        android:title="Sobre"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/sair"
        android:title="Sair"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/cadastrar"
        android:title="Adicionar Materia"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/pesquisar"
        android:title="Pesquisar"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/excluir"
        android:title="Excluir todos os registros"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Voce esta chamando o setOnQueryTextListener dentro da funcao pesquisar, mas voce lembrou de chamar essa funcao pesquisar() no seu metodo onCreate para que o listener seja de fato setado na searchView? Ou em algum outro momento esta chamando o pesquisar()? Tenta botar o listener direto na onCreate e ve o que acontecesse, nao tem todo seu codigo ai mas pode ser isso ;)

Comment: Consegui aqui, no XML, no item do campo busca troquei para 
`app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>`
 e coloquei também um  
`return true` 
no metódo
`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` 
da classe onde está o ícone da busca.

Answer (score 0):

Chame o pesquisar ou mude a implementação do mesmo para dentro do `onCreateOptionsMenu` e deixe o retorno do `onQueryTextSubmit` para true.

Comment: Consegui aqui, no XML, no item do campo busca troquei para
 `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>‌​`
 e coloquei também um `return true` no metódo
`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` da classe onde está o ícone da busca.